# Como usar Urls amigaveis?

Tags: php, url-amigável, mod-rewrite

Atualmente utilizo o `MVC` no meu projeto e quando eu acesso o meu sistema ele monstra uma url assim:

`http://localhost/view/html/cliente.html`

o que eu gostaria de obter é:

`localhost/cliente` pois é o unico arquivo chamado cliente que existe, caso tenha uma nova pasta ficar assim:

`localhost/boleto/bradesco`

sendo que seria acessado pelo:

`http://localhost/view/html/boleto/bradesco.html`

Atualmente eu uso `jQuery`,`php`,`html`, cada um separado do outro.
existe alguma solução para criar urls amigaveis de forma dinamica utilizando estas linguagens para obter este resultado?

Comment: Utilizando o exemplo do `.htaccess` do @LeoCBS, acredito que modificar a última linha (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1`) para `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view/html/$1.html` resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, você utilizar o arquivo .htaccess para tratar dinamicamente suas urls.

Abaixo um cenário de url amigáveis:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1
```

O que esse código faz é manipular a sua URL (para que ele funcione é necessário que a função ModRewrite esteja ativa no seu servidor). A partir de agora, as URL’s do seu site podem ser escritas de forma mais simples. Internamente o apache vai interpretar um endereço que está assim: seusite.com.br/noticia/12; como se fosse assim: seusite.com.br/index.php?pag=noticia/12;

Agora vamos criar o arquivo que vai manipular a URL, esse arquivo vai acessar a variável pag. Vamos chamar esse arquivo de url.php

```
< ? php
//a variavel atual, vai receber o que estiver na variável pag
//se não tiver nada, ela recebe o valor: principal“”
$atual = (isset($_GET['isw'])) ? $_GET['isw'] : 'principal';

//aqui setamos um diretório onde ficarão as páginas internas do site
$pasta = 'paginas';

//vamos testar se a variável pag possui alguma “/”
//ou seja, caso a url seja: /noticia/2
if (substr_count($atual, '/') > 0) {
//utilizamos o explode para separar os valores depois de cada “/”
$atual = explode('/', $atual);
/*testamos se depois do endereço do site, o valor da página é um arquivo existente
caso não exista, iremos atribuir o valor “erro” que será uma página de erro
personalizada que existirá dentro da pasta '$pasta', esse arquivo será incluido sempre que um endereço invalido for digitado */
$pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/" . $atual[0] . '.php')) ? $atual[0] : 'erro';
//ao que tiver depois da segunda “/” atribuiremos a variavel $id
$id = $atual[1];
//ao que tiver depois da terceira “/” atribuiremos a variavel $busca
$busca = @$atual[2];    
} else {
$pagina = (file_exists("{$pasta}/" . $atual . '.php')) ? $atual : 'erro';
$id = 0;
$frame=0;
}

//com o uso de URL amigáveis se torna necessário que arquivos sejam chamados
//com o seu caminho completo, isso porque as imagens levam em consideração a URL
// ex: <img src=”<?=$siteUrl?>/pasta/arquivo.png” />
$siteUrl = "http://seusite.com.br”;

?>
```

Arvore de diretórios do nosso site:

```
www/.htaccess
www/index.php
www/url.php
www/paginas/principal.php
www/paginas/{TODAS AS OUTRAS PAGINAS ITERNAS}
www/imagens
```

[Fonte](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/criando-url-amigaveis-com-um-codigo-simples-e-funcional)

Comment: habilitei o rewrite mod restartei o apache, criei o `.htaccess` coloquei o cod, depois criei o url.php e adicionei todo esse codigo, estao na www/.htaccess ,index.html,url.php,view,model,controller

Comment: funcionou as urls?

Comment: não funcionou, eu devo adicionar o url.php para ser executado em algum lugar ? no caso eu não estou trabalhando com a abstração do php estou apenas com o html que fica na pasta view/html/pagina.html